# Applescript to highlight text in Chrome using Javascript

Tags: safari, applescript, google-chrome, javascript

I can't figure out how to adapt this script, which highlights text in Safari, to get it to work with Google Chrome:

```
set myList to {"AppleScript", "2018", "demo@apple.com"}

tell application "Safari"
    'window.find()' command change the scroll position when it select the founded string
    set scrollPos to do JavaScript "document.designMode = 'on'; [window.pageXOffset.toString(),window.pageYOffset.toString()]" in document 1
    repeat with thisText in myList
        do JavaScript "var sel = window.getSelection();\n                sel.collapse(document.body, 0);//------    To start at the beginning of the document, not after the selectioned text\n                while (window.find('" & thisText & "', true)) {document.execCommand('HiliteColor', false, '#5cdf64');}\n                sel.collapseToEnd()" in document 1
    end repeat

    -- restore the scroll position
    do JavaScript "document.designMode = 'off';  window.scrollTo(" & (item 1 of scrollPos) & ", " & (item 2 of scrollPos) & ")" in document 1
end tell
```

Here is my Google Chrome version :

```
set myList to {"AppleScript", "2018", "CLOSED"}

tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell tab 3 of window 1 to set scrollPos to execute javascript "document.designMode = 'on'; [window.pageXOffset.toString(),window.pageYOffset.toString()]"

    repeat with thisText in myList
        execute javascript "var sel = window.getSelection();\n                sel.collapse(document.body, 0);//------    To start at the beginning of the document, not after the selectioned text\n                while (window.find('" & thisText & "', true)) {document.execCommand('HiliteColor', false, '#5cdf64');}\n                sel.collapseToEnd()"
    end repeat
    execute javascript "document.designMode = 'off';  window.scrollTo(" & (item 1 of scrollPos) & ", " & (item 2 of scrollPos) & ")"
end tell
```

Reply :

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    execute tab 3 of window 1 javascript "document.designMode = 'on'; [window.pageXOffset.toString(),window.pageYOffset.toString()]"
        --> {"0", "0"}
    execute current application javascript "var sel = window.getSelection();\n                sel.collapse(document.body, 0);//------    To start at the beginning of the document, not after the selectioned text\n                while (window.find('AppleScript', true)) {document.execCommand('HiliteColor', false, '#5cdf64');}\n                sel.collapseToEnd()"
        --> missing value
    execute current application javascript "var sel = window.getSelection();\n                sel.collapse(document.body, 0);//------    To start at the beginning of the document, not after the selectioned text\n                while (window.find('2018', true)) {document.execCommand('HiliteColor', false, '#5cdf64');}\n                sel.collapseToEnd()"
        --> missing value
    execute current application javascript "var sel = window.getSelection();\n                sel.collapse(document.body, 0);//------    To start at the beginning of the document, not after the selectioned text\n                while (window.find('CLOSED', true)) {document.execCommand('HiliteColor', false, '#5cdf64');}\n                sel.collapseToEnd()"
        --> missing value
    execute current application javascript "document.designMode = 'off';  window.scrollTo(0, 0)"
        --> missing value
end tell
Result:
missing value
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I can't get that Safari one to work either because of the ‘unknown token’ at the start of the `'window.find()' command` line. Was that line meant to be a comment? Where did you get that script from?

Comment: Just curious, what is the purpose with this script?

Comment: Hard to explain, but basically I get variable such name, IPs, and other data, and I look for this informations across different tabs, so highlighting them it's really helpfully to spot them quickly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you've enabled JavaScript from AppleScript in Google Chrome

> Executing JavaScript through AppleScript is turned off. To turn it on, from the menu bar, go to View > Developer > Allow JavaScript from Apple Events.

I've made a few changes to your script for it to work, with the changes highlighted in bold.

- The scrollPos variable and its associated handling of scrolling by getting and setting window position was superfluous, so all references to it have been removed.
- All execute verbs need to `tell window 1`, not just one verb. I've added `to tell window 1` to the enclosing tell of the application.
- The execute verb takes a reference and a JavaScript string, not just JavaScript. You are missing the reference on all your execute verbs.

```
set myList to {"AppleScript", "2018", "CLOSED"}

tell application "Google Chrome" to tell window 1
    execute active tab javascript "document.designMode = 'on';" -- scrollPos and page offset removed

    repeat with thisText in myList
        execute active tab javascript "var sel = window.getSelection();
                    sel.collapse(document.body, 0);
                    while (window.find('" & thisText & "', true)) {document.execCommand('HiliteColor', false, '#5cdf64');}
                    sel.collapseToEnd()"
    end repeat
    execute active tab javascript "document.designMode = 'off';" -- scrollPos and page offset removed
end tell
```

To run it on all tabs, wrap it with `repeat with atab in tabs`:

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to tell window 1
    repeat with atab in tabs
        execute atab javascript "document.designMode = 'on';" -- scrollPos and page offset removed

        repeat with thisText in myList
            execute atab javascript "var sel = window.getSelection();
                    sel.collapse(document.body, 0);
                    while (window.find('" & thisText & "', true)) {document.execCommand('HiliteColor', false, '#5cdf64');}
                    sel.collapseToEnd()"
        end repeat
        execute atab javascript "document.designMode = 'off';" -- scrollPos and page offset removed
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: That's perfect thank you ! do you know if I can run this highlight to every tab? I might click on different links within tabs or possibly open new one , should I run a repeat mode ?

Comment: @Kevin `repeat with atab in tabs`, see edit